# How to find id from multiple collections in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongoDB and I need help in it. Here's the example scenario. I have 3 collections: Dogs, Cats and PetsInventory and a pet data that I need to insert in PetsInventory collection.

Dogs Collection:

```
{
  "total": 3,
  "breeds": [
      {
         "_id": d1,
         "name": "labrador"
      },
      {
         "_id": d2,
         "name": "dalmatian"
      },
      {
         "_id": d3,
         "name": "husky"
      },
   ]
}
```

Cats Collection:

```
{
  "total": 3,
  "breeds": [
      {
         "_id": c1,
         "name": "persian"
      },
      {
         "_id": c2,
         "name": "ragdoll"
      },
      {
         "_id": c3,
         "name": "siamese"
      },
   ]
}
```

PetsInventory Collection:

```
{
   "total": 0,
   "items": []
}
```

Pet data to be inserted:

```
{
   "_id": p1
   "petOriginId" : c1
   "description": "male labrador"
}
```

I need to save the pet data to PetsInventory collection but before that, i need to find out if the value of the petOriginId field is existing in either Dogs collection or Cats collection otherwise it wont be inserted. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it fine if the script is Mongo Shell or do you want strictly Mongo Aggregation Query?

Comment: Any will do, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script logic should be something like below:

```
var petDataToBeInserted = {
   "_id": "p1"
   "petOriginId" : "c1"
   "description": "male labrador"
};
var foundDog = db.dogsCollection.findOne({"breeds._id": petDataToBeInserted["petOriginId"]}, {"_id": 1});
var foundCat = db.catsCollection.findOne({"breeds._id": petDataToBeInserted["petOriginId"]}, {"_id": 1});
if (foundDog != null || foundDog != null) {
    db.petsInventoryCollection.insertOne(petDataToBeInserted)  // Insert the record to based on your requirement
}
```